# Solve the equation $y=\frac{ax + b}{cx + d}$ for $x$, noting where the solution assumes $ad-bc\ne 0$

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space, mobius-transformation

[image]

These questions are from Stillwells The four Pillars of Geometry and in the context of linear fractional functions in projective geometry.

Solving for $x$ is straightforward where I get $x= \frac{b-yd}{yc-a}$ by some algebraic manipulation. But I can't spot where my manipulations assumed $ad-bc\ne 0$. What am I missing?

I have a hunch that another way to approach this could connected to the determinant of a matrix being zero and the impact that can have on whether or not an equation can be solved, but i'm not sure about that. I'm also looking to understand a bit more intuitively why $ad-bc\ne 0$ in general for linear fractional functions.

EDIT: Excerpt from the text regarding division by zero

" The linear fractional functions $f(x)= \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ we have used to describe projective mappings of lines are actually defective is the variable $x$ only runs through the set $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers. For example, the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ we used to map points of the line L1 onto points of the line L2 does not in fact map all points. It cannot set the point $x=0$ anywhere because $\frac{1}{0}$ is undefined; not can it sent any point to $y=0$ because $0 \ne \frac{1}{x}$ for any real x. This defect is neatly fixed by extending the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ to an new object $x=\infty$ and declaring that $\frac{1}{\infty}=0$ and $\frac{1}{0}=\infty$. The new object $\infty$ is none other than the point at infinity of the line L1, which is supposed to map to the point $0$ on L2. Likewise, id $\frac{1}{0}= \infty$, the point 0 on L1 is sent to the point $\infty$ on L2, as it should be."

Comment: My question is it useful for you? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3776197/homographic-function-alternative-proofs-to-obtain-ad-bc

Comment: Not really familiar with conics and hyperbolas, so it's a bit confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show your work, so it is impossible to spot where you used the assumption.

From the givens, $cx+d \neq 0$, so we can multply both sides of the equation by $cx+d$ without destroying all information in the equation.
$$  y (cx+d) = ax+b  $$
Move $x$-containing terms left and others right.
$$  c x y - ax = b - yd  $$
Un-distribute $x$s.
$$  (c y - a)x = b - yd  $$
Now, assuming $cy - a \neq 0$,
$$  x = \frac{b - yd}{cy-a}  \text{.}  $$
However, \begin{align*}
cy - a &\neq 0  \\
c \frac{ax+b}{cx+d} - a \frac{cx+d}{cx+d} &\neq 0  \\ 
\frac{acx+bc - acx - ad}{cx+d} &\neq 0 \\
\frac{bc - ad}{cx+d} &\neq 0 \text{.}
\end{align*}
We already know $cx+d \neq 0$, so this is defined and is satisfied as long as the numerator on the left-hand side is nonzero, that is, when $bc-ad \neq 0$.  Multiplying through by $-1$, when $ad - bc \neq 0$.

So you discover $ad - bc \neq 0$ is equivalent to $cy - a \neq 0$, which is necessary for inverting the relation between $x$ and $y$.  So, this map isn't a bijection unless $ad -bc \neq 0$.

Comment: The textbook states that division by zero is possible for linear fractional functions, so i'm a bit confused. I updated the original question to add this bit from the text

Comment: @user140161 : You have included text that describes how to extend the linear fractional functions to a larger domain.  This adds one point to the domain and the range, and retains bijectivity.  it does not magically make all division by zero somehow meaningful.